# Restore all emails from Archive

Tags: gmail, gmail-archive

I archived all my messages to save space, thinking that I could delete the ones I didn't want, or just put back the good ones, but now I cannot see any of them. Are they lost? I did this last night, and tried to find them, unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it seems like there would be, I couldn't quite find a question that was similar to this on this stack.

If you're trying to find all your email, and in this case you've Archived all of your email, you can access everything by clicking on "[All Mail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6576?hl=en&ref_topic=3394652)" from the left-hand menu:

> The All Mail label is added to every message. If a message has been archived, you can find it by opening the All Mail label.
>
> 1. On your computer, go to Gmail.
> 2. On the left, scroll to the bottom, then click More and then All Mail.